# Is the small resolution of a double point an lci morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = \{xy = zw\} \subset {\mathbb C}^4$ be the cone over a quadric surface and $f:Y \to X$ its usual small resolution. Is $f$ a local complete intersection morphism?

More generally (and this is mainly out of curiosity), are there any reasonable criteria to tell when a birational morphism is lci?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An lci morphism has finite $\mathrm{Tor}$-dimension, while a resolution of a (non-trivial) singularity has infinite $\mathrm{Tor}$-dimension. So, the answer is no.